# How to send multible downloadstring request parallel (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

How do I get my client to download multible htmlsource codes at the same time (parallel) and not seriel.

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

      Source1 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))
      Source2 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))
      Source3 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))
      Source4 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))
      Source5 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))
```

This request takes about 1 sec because Source1 sends the request and waits for a response before source2 can send it's request.

My current solution is to use 5 different backgroundworkers and then start each of them at the same time and have each of them send one of the requests.

```
Button1.click:
backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsync()
backgroundworker2.RunWorkerAsync()
backgroundworker3.RunWorkerAsync()
backgroundworker4.RunWorkerAsync()
backgroundworker5.RunWorkerAsync()

backgroundworker1.work:
Source1 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))

backgroundworker2.work:
Source2 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))

backgroundworker3.work:
Source3 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))

backgroundworker4.work:
Source4 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))

backgroundworker5.work:
Source5 = client.DownloadString("www.google.com"))
```

This actually works and it only takes 0.20 sec now to get all 5 sourcecodes. but is this really the only way to achieve this.

I have some pretty advances loops and it would be a pain to even split the loops into 2 separate background workers. When thats said then i probably want at least 8 separate background workers to achieve the speed I need. It would be close to impossible with this solution. Please help :)

Comment: Appart from using DownloadStringTaskAsync, just put all your url in a stack and have each thread pop one when they need it.